FTL Communication Types
How would a hard sci-fi nation with decades of technological innovation communicate FTL across Solar Systems without sending a messenger?

Are you looking for the word for this (ansible) or a description of the technology? (It's pretty much going to look like how you want it to). An explanation of how it works would fall into technobabble territory. Can you clarify what it is you're looking for in an answer?

VTC:Duplicate. This question has been asked many times. (a) There is no hard science solution to FTL because FTL insofar as we understand it today is magic. (b) We can rationalize it (which we've done many times), but in a very real sense, that's just technobabble. You might as well use Tachyons, which at this time are also magic. (c) Therefore, we could use a lot more detail about what you're trying to achieve - start by reading through previous posts to see if they help.

It not sending a messenger is the intended result, then what's wrong with sending an unmanned FTL drone? (And once you have FTL anything your science-fiction is less than hard.)

Hard sci fi? .. Short answer "it couldn't" .. slightly loger answer "no really, it couldn't" .. i spent rather a long time at one point exploring some rather deep rabbit holes to try and figure out where the idea of quantum entanglement as a method for this came from and if there might be even a smidgen of potential validity to the idea, long story short, my best guess is it probably originated with gullible and ignorant journos getting their leg yanked by piss taking physicists, and no it's not even remotely possible, like not at all, by that or any other means..

..  if you want it have it, but tis not going to be something you can call hard sci fi.

@Pelinore, What you're looking for is called the Copenhagen Interpretation, the idea that entangled particles are in some way connected. That's what Einstein was referring to when he said "spooky action at a distance." The scientific community accepts the CI until it's been proven otherwise because the alternative explanation leads to hard determinism.

@RobertRapplean nobody likes to believe they're just a clockwork toy in a clockwork world, no matter how intricate the clockwork might be.. but not liking the thought, that's just part of the clockwork

@Pelinore, Indeed. It's just hard to fathom the finest minds in physics being swayed by such bias, so everyone presumes they had a good reason for going the quantum telepathy route.

Wormholes.
A sub microscopic wormhole (WH) is 'spun up ' in a science facility. At the time of creation the two ends of the WH are captured and 'stretched' apart before the WH has time to collapse. Both ends are contained inside a sealed vacuum chamber to help maintain the WHs stability, with each end of the WH being held in place by a set of quantum field 'tweezers'. Then both both tweezers modules and their related WH entrances (lets call one alpha and one other Beta) are transferred to two separate containment pods. Importantly Alpha is always being fed a constant but minute stream of exotic matter in order to maintain the stability of the WH.
'Beta' is then loaded onto a sub light speed probe which is dispatched at a significant % of the speed of light to a target system.  'Alpha' meanwhile is placed in an orbital communications facility above the world that created it where the exotic matter feed can be maintained.
Upon arrival at the target system Beta's wormhole module is also loaded into a communications station. Communications can then be exchanged between the two systems using high bandwidth laser signals sent through the WH and both ends of the WH are now able to help maintain the exotic matter feed. The diameter of the WH can be increased as required to handle any volume of signals traffic simply by feeding in more exotic matter.
